# Projecting coordinates on to X,Y grid

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have some coordinates, [x,y] top left corner, and [x,y] bottom right corner, I want to calculate these in relation to a grid which is 600 * 585

So. `-8200,8150` = `0,0` on the grid, and `8239,-7639` = `600, 585`

How do I find e.g. position `1500,600` inside this grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a linear relationship, we want to find constants $a,b,c,d$ such that:
\begin{align*}
a(-8200) + b &= 0 \\
a(8239) + b &= 600 \\
c(8150) + d &= 0 \\
c(-7639) + d &= 585 \\
\end{align*}
Solving, we find that:
\begin{align*}
a &= \frac{600}{16439} \\
b &= \frac{4920000}{16439}\\
c &= \frac{-195}{5263} \\
d &= \frac{1589250}{5263} \\
\end{align*}
So given any coordinate $[x,y]$, we can transform it to the position on the grid given by:
$$
\left(\frac{600x + 4920000}{16439}, \frac{-195y + 1589250}{5263}\right)
$$
For example, $[1500, 600]$ would get mapped to the position:
$$
\left(\frac{5820000}{16439}, \frac{1472250}{5263}\right)
\approx (354.0361, 279.7359)
$$